# OpsHub Freezes Is it slow or Broken?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I am running OpsHub for the first time and it seems to have frozen at a specific Changeset. I can see no more activity in the TFS_Temp folder and the following lines in the Log:

```
03/27/2015 15:04:51,386 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468690372.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,397 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691396.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,547 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691545.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,634 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691634.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,634 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691634.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,683 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691683.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,706 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691706.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:51,707 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468691707.txt
03/27/2015 15:04:52,055 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1427468692053.txt
```

I am running OpsHub as administrator but still see this problem.

Am I missing something? Does it just take a long time or are these errors freezing the migration?

Comment: Hi Mark, the error that you have shared can be ignored. It's not the actual cause of the issue. Since you said that the migration has frozen at a changeset, have you tried restarting the utility? If that doesnt work, please zip and send us the logs from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online MIgration Utility\logs to ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I left this running over the weekend and its seems to have completed. I will take a look and see if its ok as there was an error dlg open when I came back to it.

Comment: Ok. Do update us when you have additional information